# performSegue(withIdentifier) not being called

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

For some reason my segue is not being performed. Here is my storyboard setup.

[image]

This code is being called in viewDidAppear of my root view controller. In the XCode debugger it says that the fetch request returned 0 results before failing on the last line due to unexpectedly finding nil. If it returned 0 results, why wouldn't my segue be performed?

```
    var fetchResult: [User] = []
    do {
        // Look for User entities in Core Data
        fetchResult = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest()) as! [User]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Fetch error")
    }
    
    if fetchResult.count == 0 {
        // New user, calculate TDEE
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTDEE", sender: self)
    }
    if fetchResult.count > 1 {
        // ERROR: too many users
        fatalError("fetch count > 1")
    }

    let user = fetchResult.first! as User
```

Comment: try this code in `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni same result

Comment: have you checked it with breakpoints? if `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTDEE", sender: self)` is calling

Comment: @DharmeshKheni It let me step into the if block, but when I try to step into performSegue it hangs for about 6 seconds then crashes with the same error. Stepping over performSegue also just crashes once it reaches the last line

Comment: It should work. Can you share any demo project where I can replicate this?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Not sure how to demo but here is the project folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uJRFrVvGFpaJTgXTJPD5evO1tDs00ILG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yes I got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your updated `RootViewController` code:

```
//Changed back to this method
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    
    var fetchResult: [User] = []
    do {
        // Look for User entities in Core Data
        fetchResult = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest()) as! [User]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Fetch error")
    }

    //Modified this with single if conditions
    if fetchResult.count == 0 {
        // New user, calculate TDEE
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTDEE", sender: self)
    } else if fetchResult.count > 1 {
        // ERROR: Too many users
        fatalError("fetch count > 1")
    } else {
        //if fetchResult.count == 1
        if let user = fetchResult.first { // New Edit Here
            if !user.didFinishSetup {
                // Didn't finish setup, re-calculate TDEE
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTDEE", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=79973891059510787468) is your updated project for more info.

Comment: I have tested it on my side and its working fine. Have you checked demo project I shared?

Comment: Google warned me of a virus and wouldn't let me download it

Comment: Also check my new Edit in answer

Comment: let me share another link

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/dharmeshkheniios/SegueDemo

Answer (score 1):

The call to `performSegue(withIdentifier:,sender:)` doesn't block the control flow. It's an asynchronous call that will make sure that UIKit eventually presents the new view controller. The code in your method will continue to execute, however.

As a result, it will encounter the last line `let user = fetchResult.first! as User` immediately afterwards. This will crash as `fetchResult.first` results is an optional and you force-unwrap it even though it is `nil` (the `fetchResult` is empty, after all). And this crash will happen even before UIKit has even started to present the new view controller.

As a general rule of thumb you should always use optional binding instead of force-unwrapping optionals.
There's excellent reading about this topic in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/10165733. I recommend you have a look at it.